# Problems connecting to nodemcu via johnny-five

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, johnny-five, firmata

I'm really having trouble connecting to my ESP8266. I was working with this setup for long time now and I didn't have to flash my boards. Now after having to use a different wifi i needed to flash the board. After doing the following

- Updating to the newest ConfigurableFirmata
- Using FirmataBuilder to download fitting firmata
- Uploading the Firmata to the ESP8266

I can't connect via Johnny-Five anymore (getting the usual timeout error). I couldn't narrow down what it exaclty is (and I have been trying all day) but these are things that I have noticed (Using ConfigurableFirmata directly as well as using firmatabuilder and StandardWifiFirmata, all with the same behaviour)

- an open Hotspot gets created even though I'm in Client Mode
- when scanning for ports I do find the Module connected to my Wifi (Serial Monitor in Debug tells me the same too) but no open port is found, even though it's specified in the firmata.

I just can't narrow down the reason. I hope you guys can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK,

this was a simple user mistake. But since I lost a whole day searching for the error and I think others might too, I'll share my mistake here.

As I pointed out I created the Firmata as Client (thinking its a client to my Hotspot). But you will have to create it as a server (as you want to connect to the board)

It's as simple as that. If you are on http://firmatabuilder.com/ make sure you choose **TCP Server** if you want to connect to your board.

Comment: How unfortunate, I lost a few days for the exact reason. This was my first attempt at connecting a microcontroller wirelessly so I overcomplicated the symptom as a blocked port, firewall issue, or poor support for the particular board I was using. Nope, just a terminology issue.